# Spring Social gives error with Enabling RedisHttpSession

Tags: redis, spring-social

I have enabled RedisHttpSession Using Annotation as below in my spring project

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

...

}
```

Without Enabling Http Session Spring Social Code Works Fine , took reference from here

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase

When I enable Redis it breaks with the following error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:67) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:50) ~[spring-data-redis-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:44) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:62) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Can anybody help what I am doing wrong here I am new to redis Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you go to Redis or any other out of process session provider all your objects that you place in session should be serializable. 
And that's what your error is actually saying, that you have some type which can't be serialized. So you got to find that type.
And when you find it probably you need to mark it with some serialization attributes or you might see that it is a type that can't be serialized at all (like Object) and that can become more complex because you need to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run Spring Social 1.1.2+ !